# python call function on short circuit

Tags: python

I have a function which has many nested if statements and sonarqube is complaining about it. There are a series of conditions that can happen and I keep track of when each occurs, return a bool and an int then increase a counter.

```
def _fix(ids, id, sch_date, cycles, dp):
    try:
        gs = cycles.get(id)
    except AttributeError:
        gs = False

    if id in ids:
        if cycles:
            if gs:
                if sch_date in gs:
                    if dp in gs[sch_date]:
                        return True, None
                    else:
                        self.d_types[4] += 1
                        return False, 4
                else:
                    self.d_types[1] += 1
                    return False, 1
            else:
                self.d_types[3] += 1
                return False, 3
        else:
            self.d_types[2] += 1
            return False, 2
    else:
        return False, None
```

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
if id in ids and cycles and gs and such_date in gs and dp in gs[sch_date]:
    do something...
```

but then I won't know where it short circuits so I won't be able to increment the counter or return the necessary int and boolean.

any ideas how I can get rid of all these if statements while still keeping the return and counter?

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): the reason you have to write this code is because of something else in `cycles.get(id)` behavior and/or `_fix(ids, id, sch_date, cycles, dp)` signature.

Comment: But even in this function it would be much clearer IMO to negate the if-conditions and return early instead of doing the nested `if`s. I don't know what specifically sonarqube complains about, but that approach seems more or less OK if you can't change the things outside this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `else` can terminate the function, so invert the test conditions. There's no need for an `else` if the function as already returned, which greatly reduces nested code.

```
if id not in ids:
    return False, None

if not cycles:
    self.d_types[2] += 1
    return False, 2

if not gs:
    self.d_types[3] += 1
    return False, 3

if sch_date not in gs:
    self.d_types[1] += 1
    return False, 1

if dp not in gs[sch_date]:
    self.d_types[4] += 1
    return False, 4

return True, None
```